# Debian 11 suddenly stopped detecting USB drives and HDMI, other USB devices and DisplayPort continue to work

Tags: debian, usb, hardware, usb-drive, hdmi

I have a rather basic Debian 11 installation, kernel 5.10.0-8-amd64. I have never tinkered much with the lower-level settings.

Overnight two things changed:

1. `xrandr` suddenly does not detect the HDMI port any more. `xrandr` lists eDP1, DP1, HDMI1, and VIRTUAL1, while before there was also an HDMI2 port. That is the one I was using (I don't think I have physical access to HDMI1). HDMI2 seems to have completely disappeared. When I plug in the cable I see no output on `udevadm monitor` or `dmesg -w`. However, the external monitor does detect the cable -- so apparently there is some voltage on the port, but the monitor also says "no signal".
2. I can't figure out a way to mount external USB drives any more. These are seen by `dmesg -w`:

   ```
   [19858.208514] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
   [19858.357789] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1221, idProduct=3234, bcdDevice= 0.00
   [19858.357793] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
   [19858.357795] usb 1-3: Product: Disk
   [19858.357797] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: USB
   ```

   However, previously I would see them in the nautilus sidebar from where I could mount them, and this does not happen any more. I can also not mount them from the command line as they don't seem to get tied to any `/dev/sdX` device.

I could confirm the HDMI issue with two different monitors and cables. There is no issue with the other external port (DP1; eDP1 is the laptop screen). The USB issue is present on all ports with three different drives. I have no issues with a USB wireless mouse and a USB ethernet adapter.

I did not run an update before this changed, but I did update after to see if it would be fixed (it wasn't). Also several reboots have not helped.

Basically I have no idea how to approach this issue. I wanted to boot a live USB to see if things worked there, but cannot create a live USB due to above problems (I may be able to try it later though). I'm of course more than happy to provide logs and command outputs if you let me know what you need.

#### `lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's always the same: the first thing you try after you post your question works.

In my case, upgrading to 5.19.0-0.deb11.2-amd64 fixed both issues.